# Eloquent - how to do "where" without the quotes appearing in the SQL and breaking it?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Here is the Laravel code:

```
$plays_in_period = $partner->plays()->where('plays.created_at', '>=','DATE(now()) - interval '.$periodDays.' day')->count();
```

Here is the SQL this produces:

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `plays` inner join `promotion` on `promotion`.`id` = `plays`.`promotion_id` 
where `promotion`.`partner_id` = 1 
and `plays`.`created_at` >= 'DATE(now()) - interval 100 day'
```

Note the quotes around `'DATE(now()) - interval 100 day'`.

This is a syntax error, it should be:

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from `plays` 
inner join `promotion` on `promotion`.`id` = `plays`.`promotion_id` where `promotion`.`partner_id` = 1 
and `plays`.`created_at` >= date(now()) - interval 100 day
```

Any ideas how I can get eloquent to drop the quotes around the final date part so it is executed?

I specifically need to use the `now()` in the DB, as I want it to be relative to the database timezone settings, not whatever the current client is using, so using Carbon, etc., is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to pass raw query segments using the [`DB::raw()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-methods):

```
$query->where('plays.created_at', '>=', DB::raw('DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ' . $periodDays . ' DAY'))...
```

This creates an *expression* object that Laravel won't wrap in quotes. Alternatively, we can use the query builder's `whereRaw()` method:

```
$query->whereRaw('plays.created_at >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL ? DAY', [ $periodDays ])...
```

The `whereRaw()` method allows us to bind parameters to a raw query to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Awesome! whereRaw is the way to go - getting the day as a query parameter is the ultimate solution.